# How do i create a navigationBar in UITableViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to IOS,

I would like to add a `UINavigationBar` to `UITableViewController`, I have tried this:

```
var navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:320, height:80))
```

then,

```
self.view .addSubview(navBar)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

You can not simplly add a `NavigationBar` to `UITableViewController` like that.

The simplest way to have `UINavigationController` and `NavigationBar` is to do it from Storyboard.

Steps:-

1. Drag the **UITableViewController** Object from **Object Library** to the Storyboard.
2. Highlight the **UITableViewController**, go to **Edit -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller** like the screen shot below:-
   [image]
3. Go to **File -> New -> File.. -> iOS -> Cocoa Touch Class**, and create a Custom TableViewController class like below screen shot:-
   [image]
4. Finally, go back to storyboard and highlight the UITableViewController object. Under the **identity inspector**, choose the custom class that you have just created like the screen shot below:- 
   [image]

You may do whatever you want with the custom class file. You may also add a custom `UINavigationController` class as well if you want and you may attach the custom class to to the object inside the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks, I know that way, can i do the same thing programmatically?

Comment: Yes, you may do it programmatically. Apple creates the storyboard to make our life easier. It is a waste not to use it. It is also not recommended as you may see the navigation very clearly from the storyboard but not from the code itself. The more code = the more time someone will have to spend in order to understand what your app is about. If you insist want to do it programmatically, you may just follow the flow on the storyboard. eg: Create a custom UINavigationViewController and then **initWithRootViewController:tableController**

Comment: sorry to bother you again, I have created a UINavigationController, how do i code the initWithRootViewController:tableController ?

Comment: its ok thanks, i found another way, in the UINavigationController viewDidLoad, i code self .pushViewController(tableviewcontroller(), animated: true)

Comment: initWithRootViewController:tableController is just an example. I am glad that you have found the way.

Comment: Great tip on `Editor > Embed In > ...`

Answer (score 5):

If this is merely the case of showing a *modal* `UITableViewController` with a navigation bar, the easiest way to do this from code is to present a `UINavigationController` with your `UITableViewController` as the `rootViewController`:

Presenting view controller:

```
let sourceSelectorTableViewController = SourceSelectorTableViewController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sourceSelectorTableViewController)

self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Destination modal UITableViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancel")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "done")
    self.title = "Pick a Source"
}
func cancel() {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func done() {
    //save things
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well the best solution will be presenting the

> UITableViewController

as

> UINavigationController

```
        let topicsList = TopicsListViewController()
        let topicsListNavContrl = UINavigationController(rootViewController: topicsList)

        presentViewController(topicsListNavContrl, animated: true) { () -> Void in
            print("completed")
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do that programmatically .

```
 DataTableViewController *vc = [[DataTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    UINavigationController  *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];


    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```